# Slowly pitch down/up a sound

Tags: pitch, pitch-shifting

I would like to slowly and smoothly pitch down or up a sound in the most easiest way.

Comment: You should add some more information to this to help people answer better. Is it a sound file or live input? If a file, how long is the sound? Do you want a constant or gradual shift? Do you need to specify curve shapes? What platform are you on? OS? You can't expect a thorough and useful answer for a one line question.

Comment: Welcome to Sound Design on Stack Exchange.  As it currently stands, this question does not provide enough detail for a definitive answer.  If you could include more details about what you are trying to do, what you have tried and what you have available for trying to do it with, that would help greatly in finding an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

serato pitch n time would do it.  you can draw the pitch curve

Answer (score 0):

The easiest tool would be probably be [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). It's free, and has a sliding time/pitch effect.

Comment: But I cannot smoothly pitch sound down, I can only pitch the sound down in parts which is not smooth.